# URL rewriting with 3 parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Thanks for helping me resolve this issue. I have urls looking like:

```
http://local-host/enc/?aya-bi-aya=aya-6&assurah=an-nisa&attab=attakhrij
```

The goal is to make them appear like:

```
http://local-host/enc/aya-bi-aya/an-nisa/aya-6/attakhrij
```

The rules I am defining in my .htaccess are:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^aya-bi-aya/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$   ?aya-bi-aya=$2&assurah=$1&attab=$3   [L]
# END WordPress
```

I receive a 404 page. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this htaccess file in your `/enc/` directory?

Comment: My htaccess file is in /enc/. Thanks for your time. @JonLin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated this rule as per the new info shared by you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aya-bi-aya/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$  ?aya-bi-aya=$2&assurah=$1&attab=$3 [L]
```

I'm using a character class `\w` which is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Makes the rule more readable and `/?` at the end allows your rule to work with the URLs that don't have a trailing slash.

Comment: I preserved your edit and updated the rule to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Everything after the "?" in the original request (i.e., the "query string") is not part of the main URL.

However, you can access the query string via:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ....
```

So something more like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /enc/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^aya-bi-aya=([^&]*)\&assurah=([^&]*)\&attab=([^&]*)$    
RewriteRule   .*  /enc/aya-bi-aya/%1/%2/%3   [L,R=301]*
```

The L = last, R = redirect to change the displayed URL in the user's browser

Comment: I did not test that; but the key idea (I think) is that you need to consult %{QUERY_STRING}.